# Central Limit Theorem with linear transformation?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $Z=(z_{1},...,z_{m})^T$ is m dimensional vector, each $z_{i}$ is independent identical distribution with mean 0. If we do linear transformation like: 
$$X = \Gamma Z$$
where $\Gamma$ is $p*m(p<m)$ matrix, $\Sigma = \Gamma \Gamma^T $.

Then will the independent $X_{1}$ sample from $X$, like $X_{1}^{T}X_{1}/\sqrt{p}$ be normal distribution when p goes to infinity? If not, what condition need for $\Sigma$?

Thanks so much for your help~